# parseing JSON data into HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to output the results of a data.json file, but I keep getting the wrong output. at first I was getting [obj obj], but I tried this method, and it seems to be getting the index.

I even removed the outside curly braces and the games title from the JSON file, but still not working. At the moment, I am just trying to console the game title, but the idea is to output the whole thing.

```
//my JSON is in a different file

{
  "games" : [
    {
      "gameImg"   : "img/deathstranding.jpg",
      "gameTitle" : "Death Stranding",
      "gameInfo"  : "some game info"
    },
    {
      "gameImg"   : "img/deathstranding.jpg",
      "gameTitle" : "Death Stranding",
      "gameInfo"  : "some game info"
    }
  ]
}

// JS

function init2() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/data.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
          JSON.stringify(data);
          $.each(data, function( val ) {
          var items = [];
          items.push( "<li>" + val + "</li>" );
          console.log('gameTittle:', items);
        });
      }
    });
}
init2();
```

Comment: Why do you do `stringify`?

Comment: I know, I don't need, I was just trying different things

Answer (score 0):

`$.each(data, function( val ) {}`

Here you are making a mistake, first parameter inside $.each function is an index and second is actual value, change it to:

`$.each(data, function( index, val ) {...}`

Documentation: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)